# URLParameter value bug in Intelligencia.UrlRewriter

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

my rewrite rule is

**<rewriter>

<rewrite url="~/categories/([0-9,A-Z,a-z,-]+)/(.+).aspx" to="~/inventory/product-list.aspx?categorycode=$1" processing="stop"/>

</rewriter>**

it works for url with

**/category/abc/abc.aspx**

but causes problem with

**/category/con/abc.aspx**

i dont understand why?

if we pass "**con**" as url parameter value in any site used by Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.
you may find similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have researched so much and found an answer.

Actually IIS restricts us from use certain keywords in URL like

**COM1-9, LPT1-9, AUX, PRT, NUL, CON**

but we can solve this by using following settings in **web.config** file.

<configuration>
     <system.web>

         <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

    </system.web>

</configuration>

It solved my problem.